# How to custom gauge js

Tags: javascript, gauge, jsgauge

I am doing gauge indicator and choose https://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/

my script is

```
var opts = {
          angle: -0.12, // The span of the gauge arc
          lineWidth: 0.16, // The line thickness
          radiusScale: 1, // Relative radius
          pointer: {
            length: 0.35, // // Relative to gauge radius
            strokeWidth: 0.035, // The thickness
            color: '#000000' // Fill color
          },
          limitMax: false,     // If false, max value increases automatically if value > maxValue
          limitMin: false,     // If true, the min value of the gauge will be fixed
          colorStart: '#6FADCF',   // Colors
          colorStop: '#8FC0DA',    // just experiment with them
          strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',  // to see which ones work best for you
          generateGradient: true,
          highDpiSupport: true,     // High resolution support
          // renderTicks is Optional
          renderTicks: {
            divisions: 5,
            divWidth: 0.6,
            divLength: 0.2,
            divColor: '#333333',
            subDivisions: 5,
            subLength: 0.44,
            subWidth: 0.4,
            subColor: '#666666'
          },
            staticZones: [
               {strokeStyle: "#F6424C", min: 0, max: 500}, // Red from 100 to 130
               {strokeStyle: "#F9915A", min: 500, max: 550}, // Yellow
               {strokeStyle: "#FFE848", min: 550, max: 650}, // Green
               {strokeStyle: "#F9915A", min: 650, max: 750}, // Yellow
               {strokeStyle: "#358607", min: 750, max: 1000}  // Red
            ],
            staticLabels: {
              font: "12px sans-serif",  // Specifies font
              labels: [0, 500, 550, 650, 750, 1000],  // Print labels at these values
              color: "#414141",  // Optional: Label text color
              fractionDigits: 0  // Optional: Numerical precision. 0=round off.
            }

        };
        var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // your canvas element
        var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
        gauge.maxValue = 1000; // set max gauge value
        gauge.setMinValue(0);  // Prefer setter over gauge.minValue = 0
        gauge.animationSpeed = 34; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
        gauge.set(552); // set actual value
```

and I have go[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC80c.png)

but i need such view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8cFy.png) Question is how can do this? If it's impossible with this, what you can offer me. Thanks for attention!

Comment: That gauge doesn't increment by the same units, is that correct? Like from 0-500 is the same as 750-1000 on the image you posted that you want to mimic.

Comment: It looks like the library you chose only supports printing the label using the value at that position, so you would either have to model your gauge with each 'tick' being equal width, or find another library.